# Gimp: I can't find any of the controls or toolbars that I used to be able to see

Tags: gimp

I used to use Gimp and really liked it but it's been awhile. Now when I want to use it again, the only thing I can see is the tiny little box with the image. I can't find any of the controls or toolbars that I used to be able to see. Can I get that back? I can't use the program the way it is.

Answer (score 3):

Open GIMP and the from the GIMP menu select *Windows* -> uncheck *Hide Docks*. This is also a useful feature if you're precisely cropping a large image and you temporarily need extra real estate in the image pane in order to show the whole image with a larger Zoom level.

Also see: [I accidentally closed my GIMP toolbox. Can I get it back?](https://superuser.com/questions/645532/i-accidentally-closed-my-gimp-toolbox-can-i-get-it-back). In the lower right-hand corner of the Toolbox window there is a blue button surrounded by a yellow arrow that says if you move the mouse cursor over it: "Reset to default values **Shift** Reset all tool options".